# Is there any Yahoo Invisible Scanners still working?

Tags: yahoo-messenger

I used to use some sites like ydetector.com and invisible-scanner.com to check if my sister is online because I don't like to drop her a ton of offline messages. But is seems that none of these sites working. Does anybody know one that working ?

Answer (score 2):

<del>I'm using [Yahoo Status Check](http://yahoo-status.com/). It also tells you if the user is invisible or just offline.</del>

There is [Status Detect](http://www.statusdetect.com/) and it’s working at the moment (16/12/2012).

<del>And yes, both are working at the moment of this answer.</del>

Edit:

[image]

Comment: I don't see they're working. I told my friend to be invisible but they both returned the results as offline.

Comment: @user458773 **Yahoo Status Check** is using http://www.imvisible.info/ so you might want to check that service as well. I was always able to see when a user is invisible and when online.

Comment: imvisible.info doesn't work either. I checked my own ID when I was invisible but it did show my ID as offline.

Comment: @user458773 **Yahoo Status Check** works just fine for me. Check the image I've added to my answer.

Comment: Strange ! Just checked it again already and still didn't work for me.